Chrome Use GPU While downloading ZIP files
I have a web application. Which is used to send files And there is a functionality that download all files in the ZIP formate.
The Problem is when i download any zip file my web browser use GPU.
is it conserning or it is normal thing.
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open(method, url, true);
                xhr.responseType = 'blob';
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

                xhr.send(JSON.stringify(dataBody));

                xhr.onprogress = function (e) {
                    // console.log("load", e);

                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        const progress = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                        setProgress(Math.ceil(progress));
                    }
                };

                xhr.onload = function (e) {
                    if (this.status === 200) {
                        const blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: 'application/zip' });
                        const urls = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        const link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.href = urls;
                        link.setAttribute('download', `FileShare-${Date.now()}.zip`);
                        document.body.appendChild(link);
                        link.click();
                        link.remove();
                    }
                };

                // xhr on error
                xhr.onerror = function (e) {
                    console.log("error in xhr", e);
                    setIsDownloadProgress(false);
                    setProgress(0);

                  
                };

                xhr.onloadend = function (e) {
                    setIsDownloadProgress(false);
                    setProgress(0);
                    setToastMessage((prev) => {
                        return {
                            ...prev,
                            show: false,
                        }
                    });
                }


This behaviour is by design.  Google Chrome passes a lot of tasks onto the GPU in order to preserve CPU usage and improve overall performance.
Additionally, the standard behaviour of Chrome is to open a single socket when downloading files.  By enabling parallel downloading, this can improve performance.
To enable, type chrome://flags/ in the address bar, navigate down to Parallel Downloading, and select "Enable".  Now, restart your browser.
Edit:  Corrected typo.
